# IronPython Profiler

Tags: profiling, ironpython

I need to find a good IronPython profiler. On the net I found several Python profilers that won't work under IronPython or are not available. The best one so far is the one described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/curth/2009/03/30/an-ironpython-profiler/). It prints method names, inclusive/exclusive times and the number of calls. But it seems to be buggy because it doesn't print ALL of the methods and for some reason both the inclusive and exclusive times are the same.

Does anyone know about another way of profiling IronPython 2.7.5 code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771

Comment: Consider having a few files full of code I don't know too well and a complex call structure. I am already doing this kind of manual profiling but it takes ages if the complexity of a program is too high.

Comment: What is your motivation and workload? Is it mostly python or are there .net libraries involved? Have you had a look if a classic .net profiler helps at all?

Comment: There are .NET libraries involved but on a higher level. A regular .NET profiler won't help as it is almost pure python code.